# set up a multi module maven project in vs code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up a multi module maven project in vs code with no luck until now. And google doesn't give any useful hints (or I search the wrong key words).

First, I created a parent project with the following pom content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.novus</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>auth</module>
  </modules>

  <name>parent</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.boot.dependencies.version>2.7.1</spring.boot.dependencies.version>
    <spring.cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring.cloud.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.dependencies.version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.version}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
</project>
```

As you see, I specified the `packaging` as `pom` and added a module `auth` to it.

After that I added a sub folder `auth` to the parent folder and generated a new java maven project in it with this pom content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.novus</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
  
  <name>auth</name>
 
</project>
```

I see now the `auth` project in the maven tab:

[image: maven tab]

but the console reports an error: `App.java is not on the classpath of project parent, only syntax errors are reported`. And f. e. the dependencies specified in the parent pom aren't added to this sub module.

And if I right click on the `src` folder of the `auth` sub module and select `Add Folder to Java Source Path` I get this error in vs code: `Unsupported operation. Please use pom.xml file to manage the source directories of maven project.`

And of course the `auth` project isn't recognized as a java project:

[image: java project tab]

The question is, how to set up a multi module maven project in vs code the right way?

Comment: If you don't change your maven configuration in pom.xml. Default source folder is `src/main/java`
See : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Do you put your code in this folder or change your `<sourceDirectory>` ?

Comment: I have my doubts that your setup will work because you have defined source/target to 1.7 and using most recent version of spring boot. You need at least JDK8 for runtime (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.1/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.system-requirements)

Comment: Here are two GitHub issues that should help you.[1248](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1248), [821](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/821).